# Change signature of com visible method to use stdcall and return an interface

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, com, com-interop

We are currently trying to change the signature of a COM-visible method, as this would allow us to use the same interface without thinking whether the actual object has been created via COM or not.

To do so, we defined an interface in Delphi like:

```
ISomeInterface = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{67C7E941-DB69-41A0-B325-1C76ADEFFC33}']
  function GetSomeValue: Integer; stdcall;
  function GetInterface: ISomeInterface; stdcall;
  procedure GetInterface2(out pParam: ISomeInterface); stdcall;
end;
```

and an according interface in C#

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("67C7E941-DB69-41A0-B325-1C76ADEFFC33")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetSomeValue();
    [PreserveSig]
    ISomeInterface GetInterface();
    [PreserveSig]
    void GetInterface2(out ISomeInterface);
}
```

The signatures we can see in the TLB seem to be just as intended. Signatures and CallingConventions match each other. We can compile, create objects implementing the interface and use the methods 'GetSomeValue' and 'GetInterface2'.

But calling the 'GetInterface' function is not working (it seems like the CLR is immediately terminated, not even providing an exception).

This finally results in the question: Is it possible to change the return type for com methods to return an interface (by ref)? And if so, how?

Furthermore: It seems to be possible to return values 'by value' (like in GetSomeValue), but is this valid? Or do COM-Methods definitely have to return an HResult?